# how to communicate with ror program in python

Tags: python, web-services, rest, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a application which use rails to do the CRUD operation,it's handy

now i want to write a crawler use python,after that i want to save the data to db,

so my question is how to python communicate with ror program?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any idea about python or rails (only grails :) but the easiest solution (if you don't want the python script to touch the DB) would be to implement a controller action for the REST PUT method in your rails application and call it from your python crawler with the crawled data.

Now, all the rails controller has to do is to inster the data into your database.

Answer (score 0):

Via the CRUD interface, seems the obvious solution.